# About numbering of figures and tables in appendix {elsarticle.cls}

Tags: floats, numbering, appendices, elsarticle

When I am using `elsarticle.cls` to write papers, I always meet the following problem. If I already have one picture (table) in main text and then I put another picture (table) in appendix, the numbering of the picture (table) in appendix is not Figure A.1 (Table A.1) but Figure A.2 (Table A.2).

I tried to modify the `elsarticle.cls` by adding

```
\renewcommand\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}%
  \setcounter{equation}{0}
  \setcounter{figure}{0}
  \setcounter{table}{0}
  ....
```

But I failed, always encountering warnings and errors.

Here is the test code:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\begin{table}[h]
  \caption{Test}\label{Tab_1}
  \centering{}
  \begin{tabular}{c|c}
  \hline
  $E(\mathrm{Mpa})$ & $\nu$\\
  \hline
  $6.8\times10^4$ & 0.21\\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\appendix
\section{Test}
\begin{table}[h]
  \caption{Test}\label{Tab_2}
  \centering{}
  \begin{tabular}{c|c}
  \hline
  $E(\mathrm{Mpa})$ & $\nu$\\
  \hline
  $6.8\times10^4$ & 0.21\\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

If we put picture we meet also the same problem.I do not know why this happen. Does mean that in appendix we can not put any table or figure? Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Could you make your snippet into a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)?

Answer (score 5):

A copy and paste from `elsarticle.cls`

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}%
  \setcounter{equation}{0}%
  \setcounter{table}{0}%------------ << add
  \setcounter{figure}{0}%----------- << add
  \gdef\theequation{\@Alph\c@section.\arabic{equation}}%
  \gdef\thefigure{\@Alph\c@section.\arabic{figure}}%
  \gdef\thetable{\@Alph\c@section.\arabic{table}}%
  \gdef\thesection{\appendixname\@Alph\c@section}%
  \@addtoreset{equation}{section}%
  \@addtoreset{table}{section}%----- << add
  \@addtoreset{figure}{section}%---- << add
}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, adding the following lines after `\appendix` helps?

```
\appendix
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\numberwithin{table}{section}
```